# uBlock blocks POST request

Tags: http-post, commerce, ublock-origin

I have the following button on my page:

```
<div class="item__menu">
    <div class="btn-group js-cartItemDetailGroup">
        <div class="remove-button">
            <form id="cartEntryActionForm" action="<domain-path>/cart" method="post">
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="1234">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="js-execute-entry-action-button" id="actionEntry_0" 
                data-entry-action-url="<domain-path>/cart/entry/execute/REMOVE" 
                data-entry-action="REMOVE" 
                data-entry-product-code="123456789" 
                data-entry-initial-quantity="1" 
                data-action-entry-numbers="0">
                    <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems that uBlock blocks the button click / POST request for any reason despite the source and target server are the same. Do you guys know how I can adjust the code so that uBlock lets it pass? I don't want to tell my users to switch off the add blocker.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there was a GA call within the /REMOVE function which of course is blocked by uBlock. As a result the whole function was not executed.